# Why am I getting this xpath error using Requests?

Tags: python, json, xmlhttprequest, python-requests

I am using the following code to mimic and XHR request and am getting an xpath error that the URL and parameters generated are not valid, despite them all looking fine:

```
import json
import requests
import jsonobject
import simplejson

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'
params = {
            'category': 'shots',
            'subcategory': 'situations',
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'playerId': '',
            'teamIds': '',
            'matchId': '',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'tournamentOptions': '2',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': '',
            'age': '',
            'ageComparisonType': '',
            'appearances': '',
            'appearancesComparisonType': '0',
            'field': '',
            'nationality': '',
            'positionOptions': '%27FW%27,%27AML%27,%27AMC%27,%27AMR%27,%27ML%27,%27MC%27,%27MR%27,%27DMC%27,%27DL%27,%27DC%27,%27DR%27,%27GK%27,%27Sub%27',
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'isMinApp': '',
            'page': '1',
            'includeZeroValues': '',
            'numberOfPlayersToPick': '10'
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print responser.status_code
print responser.url
responser = responser.json()
print responser
```

Using the developer tools I have grabbed a screen shot of what the xhr request is composed of, which is in the picture below:

[image]

Can anyone see anything that is obviously wrong with my code? Even just a typo?

Thanks

Comment: When I run this, I don't get any "xpath error", I get an error saying "We are unable to respond to you at the moment but we will be back shortly." In other words, the service is down. If you're getting a different error, please show us the output or traceback

Comment: Also, that screenshot is unreadable even with my contacts in and on a Retina screen. Please copy the URL (or whatever part is important) and paste it as text.

Comment: I suspect you need to un-url-encode those `%27`s into `'`s, but it's hard to be sure without clearer information about the error you're getting.

Comment: @abarnert right click and open image in new tab.

Comment: @AndrewLorente hi, thanks for replying. im not sure what you mean there. could you please explain?

Comment: @abarnert also, the print responser.url response is 'http://www.whoscored.com/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'

Comment: @AndrewLorente i get it now. this worked: 'positionOptions': "'FW','AML','AMC','AMR','ML','MC','MR','DMC','DL','DC','DR','GK','Sub'",

Comment: That's the exact same error I got. Where do you see anything about xpath in that error message?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the end:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics'
params = {
            'category': 'shots',
            'subcategory': 'situations',
            'statsAccumulationType': '0',
            'isCurrent': 'true',
            'playerId': '',
            'teamIds': '',
            'matchId': '',
            'stageId': '9155',
            'tournamentOptions': '2',
            'sortBy': 'Rating',
            'sortAscending': '',
            'age': '',
            'ageComparisonType': '',
            'appearances': '',
            'appearancesComparisonType': '0',
            'field': '',
            'nationality': '',
            'positionOptions': "'FW','AML','AMC','AMR','ML','MC','MR','DMC','DL','DC','DR','GK','Sub'",
            'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
            'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
            'isMinApp': '',
            'page': '1',
            'includeZeroValues': '',
            'numberOfPlayersToPick': '10'
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print responser.status_code
print responser.url
responser = responser.json()
print responser
```

Answer (score 0):

The error URL you're getting, according to your comments, is http://www.whoscored.com/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics%27

The contents of that error page say:

> We are unable to respond to you at the moment but we will be back shortly.
>
> Please check us again soon and thanks for your patience.
>
> WhoScored.com

When I test your code, I get the same error. When I paste the same URL into the browser, I get the same error.

There is nothing about xpath in that error message. The problem appears to be that the server is temporarily not working. If so, there is nothing you can do in your code to fix it.

Comment: How _could_ it mean xpath error? The `x` isn't anywhere near the `path`. It's part of `aspx`, which is the name for "web forms" in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET).